# Java Code Execution Puzzle -- Skipping Lines Without Exception Thrown

Tags: java, spring

I used a debugger to trace an issue. I was very puzzled about how the code was executed. Please see the attached image. Originally after the Line 189 was executed, the execution skipped the lines after it such as Line 194 and Line 196, and jumped to Line 198. I suspected there could be an exception at Line 189 so I wrapped it with a try-catch. However, it still jumped to Line 198 after Line 189 was executed.

[image]

The following was the original code (https://github.com/de-luxe/burstcoin-jminer/blob/master/src/main/java/burstcoin/jminer/core/round/Round.java) without the try-catch (Line 188 - LIne 195 are the interest). The debugger was running under the configuration "useOpenCl=false". If "useOpenCl=true", the program can run without issues, i.e., the lines  after Line 189 (Line 188 in original code) will be executed normally on an OpenCl supported machine. Obviously, I was trying to deploy it without using OpenCl and due to this issue, I cannot do it. I have done Java programming for many years, and this is really intriguing to me how the code could execute by skipping some lines without exceptions thrown anywhere.

```
  // start reader
    int scoopNumber = calcScoopNumber(event.getBlockNumber(), event.getGenerationSignature());
    reader.read(previousBlockNumber, blockNumber, generationSignature, scoopNumber, lastBestCommittedDeadline, networkQuality);

    // ui event
    publisher.publishEvent(new RoundStartedEvent(restart, blockNumber, scoopNumber, plots.getSize(), targetDeadline, baseTarget, generationSignature));

    network.checkLastWinner(blockNumber);
```

Comment: Maybe catch(Throwable th) instead of (Exception e)? Also, sometimes debuggers give odd behavior if code and .class files are out of sync; try a clean build?

Comment: @SteveHarrington Thanks a lot. You are right -- catch the Throwable. Will you put it as an answer to get the points.

Comment: will do; glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to `catch(Throwable th)` instead of `(Exception e)`

Comment: I had my doubts, so I cloned the code.  Nowhere in the project or any of its dependencies is a Throwable being thrown.  That would be bizarre.  I think you were correct about the code and .class files being out of sync.